# How to call ajax kendo mvc function with jquery

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

i'm using kendo mvc grid.i want Read/Update functions run by manuly(jquery)
it's my function:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("Eqp_Read", "ShiftReports"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call [datasource](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/datasource) [read](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/read) method.

```
$("#your_grid_id").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kendo grid MVC, you can use. Events to specify your own javascript functions for `read`, `update`, `save` and so on. 
    In those javascript functions, you can write ajax calls like below.

Example:

```
.Events(
    m => m.Save("SaveFunc")
    .Edit("EditFunc")
    .DataBound("ReadFunc")
)
```

And in JavaScript:

```
function SaveFunc(e) {
    //Your ajax code here
}
```